# Trying to load a simple html in Django but it appears GET /homepage/ HTTP/1.1" 500 145

Tags: python, django, django-views, django-templates, django-urls

I did the [Tutorial](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/intro/tutorial01/) for the polling app on the official Django web page and everything worked out fine. Since I already have some HTML from my old website I wanted to reuse some of that. I decided to create an app called "homepage" for the main page you get when you visit the page (if this is bad practice, let me know). Since the main page is more or less just some introductory text and a navigation menu without any fancy functionality I did not create a DB (models) in this case. Furthermore I was sure that Django is able to simply deliver some plain static html without a database provided.

The urls.py in the hompage app folder looks like:

```
from django.urls import path
from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.index1, name='index1'),]
```

and the view.py like this

```
from django.http import HttpResponse
from django.shortcuts import render


def index(request):
    return HttpResponse("Hello, world. You're at the polls index.")
```

Everything works out fine. As soon as I try to load a html file (here a simple one just to check if it works) I get the error message. The new view.py looks like in the tutorial suggested:

```
def index(request):
    latest_question_list = 'Hallo'
    context = {'latest_question_list': latest_question_list}
    return render(request, 'homepage/index.html', context)
```

The folder structure is like suggested in the tutorial:

```
myproject_dir/myproject

myproject_dir/homepage/templates/hompage/index.html
```

The html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>My test page</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <p>This is my page</p>
    <p>{{latest_question_list}}</p>
  </body>
</html>
```

Again, it works out fine with the poll app, which I have still working in the same project folder. This leaves me pretty confused and I'm looking forward to get some input.

Comment: What's the problem you exactly facing?

Comment: Writing name of app as `homepage` is not a bad practice but writing any other inbuilt django module name like `admin` etc. is bad practice.

Comment: @Sunderam The problem is that it does not load the index.html and I get a "GET /homepage/ HTTP/1.1" 500 145" error and I don't know why.

Comment: @SHA256man, could you provide your full error traceback.

Answer (score 1):

Set the default path in your project's `urls.py` in `urlpatterns` list.

```
from django.urls import path,include

urlpatterns=[
path('',include('homepage.urls'))
]
```

Then its next `route` will be decided through your app's `urls.py` that is `homepage`.

Comment: Here admin is already included, don't remove that route.

Comment: You are correct, @Sunderam, if the name of the view is different than the name in the path, the server will not even start.  Thanks for pointing that out.  I will be deleting / editing my answer.  At the same time, not having the path `path('',include('homepage.urls'))` as you describe would lead to a 404 page not found error, not a 500 internal server error like the OP put in the title of his question.  We need to see more of the OP's code, I think.

Comment: @raphael you are right, can you spend some time on my question related to django  by going in my profile, because somehow  i am not able to share the link.